# uk visitor visa ban for 10 years on wrong assumptions

Tags: uk, egyptian-citizens, deception

my mother in law got ban for 10 years based on deception as she have been refused befor and she didnt say so but the truth she applyed before and before any decsion she with drawel her passport from the embassy as she got a haj visa (saudi aribia visa) and she state the at the notes in second application so what we can do to prove that the decion made on wrong assumptions?

Comment: Hello user60866, welcome to Travel SE. Usually we require a scan of the documents, with personal details blanked out, but when it comes to a ban I guess she will need the servies of an UK solicitor and not just the comments of an internet Q&A forum.

Comment: You should probably contact a solicitor.

Comment: How is this off-topic when we have a huge repository of questions dealing with visa refusals, bans and deception wrt UK? IMO this should be on hold because it is unclear and not because it is off topic.

Comment: The ECOs are known to misuse their powers. They should be held accountable to the same standards they expect the applicants to be.

Comment: @RedBaron, perhaps "off topic" is putting it badly, but this question has little detail and I find it unlikely that it will become a useful Q&A entry.